# yii2 websocket closes immediately after open

Tags: websocket, yii2

I have an websocket app working on yii2. Here's my server side (using https://github.com/consik/yii2-websocket):

```
class ChatServer extends WebSocketServer
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->on(self::EVENT_CLIENT_CONNECTED, function(WSClientEvent $e) {

            $user = User::findById(\Yii::$app->user->identity->id);
            $e->client->id = $user->id;
        });
        $this->on(self::EVENT_CLIENT_DISCONNECTED, function(WSClientEvent $e){

        });
    }
    protected function getCommand(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {
        $request = json_decode($msg, true);
        return !empty($request['action']) ? $request['action'] : parent::getCommand($from, $msg);
    }
    public function commandChat(ConnectionInterface $client, $msg)
    {
        $request = json_decode($msg);
        $result = ['message' => ''];
        if (!isset($request->recipient_id) || !isset($request->message)) {
            $client->send(json_encode(['success' => false]));
        }

        $user = User::findById(\Yii::$app->user->identity->id);


        if (!$user->isFriend($request->recipient_id)) {
            $client->send(json_encode(['success' => false]));
        }

        $message = new Message();
        $message->sender_id = $user->id;
        $message->receiver_id = $request->receiver_id;
        $message->text = $request->message;

        if ($message->save())
        {
            $result['message'] = 'Sended.';
            foreach($this->clients as $chatClient) {
                if ($chatClient->id == $message->receiver_id) {
                    $chatClient->send( json_encode([
                        'type' => 'newMessage',
                        'message' => $message->text
                    ]) );
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $result['message'] = 'Some error here.';
        }
        $client->send( json_encode($result) );
    }
}
```

And this is my client side:

```
$(function() {
        var chat = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8079/');

        chat.onopen = function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            console.log('connected!');
        };
        chat.onclose = function(event) {
          console.log('closed');
        };

        $('#btnSend').click(function() {
            if ($('#message').val()) {
                chat.send( JSON.stringify({'action' : 'chat', 'message' : $('#message').val()}) );
            } else {
                alert('Enter the message')
            }
        })
    });
```

But when I open this page, I got this in console: 

`connected!
closed`
And when I tried to send a message via `chat.send`, I got `WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.`.
What should I do here? Why my websocket closes so fast?

And what's the best decision for websockets on yii2?

P.S. Edit my js:

```
var chat = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/');    
    chat._original_send_func = chat.send;
    chat.send = function(data) {
       if(this.readyState == 1) {
           this._original_send_func(data);
       }         
       else {
           console.log('No')
       }

       }.bind(chat);
```

And when I tried to send a message, `readyState` not equals to 1. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the SocketServer is crashing in function `init()` just after the client is connected. One reason for this is if you are starting the server using `php-cli` then the reason for the crash will be the line `$user = User::findById(\Yii::$app->user->identity->id);` since Console App don't have user identity component this throws an Exception which shuts down the server.